# Laravel displaying base64 image

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, base64

How can I send e-mail with attached image if I receive the data in base64 format?

Here is mail template:

```
<h1>You got mail from - {{$user->name}}</h1>

<h2>Date:</h2>
<p>{{$post->created_at}}</p>
<h2>Message:</h2>
<p>{{$post->body}}</p>

<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{$image}}">

<div>
</div>
```

And the logic:

```
public function createPost()
{
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser();
    $user->posts()->create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'body' => Input::get('comment.body')]);

    Mail::send('mail.template', [
        'image' => Input::get('image'),
        'user'  => $user,
        'post'  => Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()->last(),
    ], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('xyz@app.com', 'XYZ');

        $m->to('xyz@gmail.com', $user->name)->subject('Subject');
    });
}
```

From this I only get mail with full base64 string...`img` tag gets ignored

Comment: Does ```Input::get('image')``` contain base64 image?

Comment: Yes. I have pasted it to http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter and it shows me the image

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to save the image first in order to attach it as [Viktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4841755/viktor) suggested although I don't have Laravel 5.3. so the method is somehow different.

User may or may not send the picture, so the method is as follows:

```
$destinationPath = null;
        if($request->has('image')){
            // save received base64 image
            $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/sent/uploaded' . time() . '.jpg';
            $base64 = $request->get('image');
            file_put_contents($destinationPath, base64_decode($base64));
        }
```

And then attach the saved image to the mail:

```
Mail::send('mail.template', [
    'user'  => $user,
    'post'  => Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()->last(),
], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('xyz@app.com', 'XYZ');

    $m->to('xyz@gmail.com', $user->name)->subject('Subject');

    if($request->has('image')){
        $m->attach($destinationPath);
    }
});
```

The mail template:

```
<h1>You got mail from - {{$user->name}}</h1>

<h2>Date:</h2>
<p>{{$post->created_at}}</p>
<h2>Message:</h2>
<p>{{$post->body}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Attachments
>
> To add attachments to an email, use the attach method within the
>   mailable class' build method. The attach method accepts the full path
>   to the file as its first argument:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->attach('/path/to/file');
}
```

More information [here (for Laravel 5.3)](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#attachments).
I hope, it will be helpful.

Comment: Well according to link you posted, gmail doesn't support embedding images at all =/ Btw, this solution you posted gives me the same result